# Can't access observable array in viewmodel in knockout.js mvvm to manipulate items

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel, single-page-application, ko.observablearray, knockout-mvvm

I'm working on an MVVM web app using Knockout.js, require.js etc. The problem is that I can't access items within a property (of type observable array) in my viewmodel.

Sample contract model:

```
define('model.contract', ['ko'],
    function (ko) {
        var Contract = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.id = ko.observable();
            self.subject = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

            self.shoppingItems = ko.observableArray();

           };
           return Contract;
    });
```

Sample view model:

```
define('vm.contract', ['ko'],
    function (ko) {
        var contract = ko.observable(), // Is initialised as viewmodel activates

            deleteCmd = function () {

                var selectedId = getSelectedId(),
                    deletedId = contract.shoppingItems.remove(function (item) { return item.id === selectedId; });

                alert('Item ' + deletedId[0].id + ' was deleted!');
            };

        return {
            contract: contract,
            deleteCmd: deleteCmd
        };
    });
```

Sample view:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: shoppingItemTemplate, foreach: contract().shoppingItems}"></div>
<button data-bind="click: deleteCmd">Delete Selected</button>
```

All I need to access in viewmodel is `contract.shoppingItems` and all I get is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you defined your `contract` as `observableArray` rather than just `observable`?

Also do not forget that you should call `contract()` to get value of `contract` observable:

```
// ...
deletedId = contract().shoppingItems.remove(function (item) { return item.id === selectedId; });
// ...
```

Update:
Just noticed that you improperly defined `model.contract`. Place your `return Contract` outside of `Contract` definition block :)

```
define('model.contract', ['ko'],
    function (ko) {
        var Contract = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.id = ko.observable();
            self.subject = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

            self.shoppingItems = ko.observableArray();
         };

        return Contract;
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I corrected it. And you're right about the `contract()` but the problem persists.

Comment: Well, this is awkward, but this problem only existed here not in my original code. I corrected here too. Actually my model works fine and that's why my bindings for `shoppingItems` list work.